# flex - querying a date var and changing minutes

Tags: apache-flex

I'm trying to find out what the time is through a Date var and changing the hours in it. Does anyone know how to do that? I guess in pseudo-code i would like something like this:

```
function updateTime(d:Date)Void
{
  Var nowTime:Date() = new Date();
  if (d.getHour() < nowTime.getHour()+1)
     d = nowTime;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Did you checked this :http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Date.html?filter_flash=cs5&filter_flashplayer=10.2&filter_air=2.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to change hours there is a function `setHours()`. Than it will be like this :

```
d.setHours(nowTime.getHour());
```